Использование DRDB для кластеризации Postgresql и clickhouse
Изучал методы кластеризации и наткнулся на такие вещи как rsync и drdb.
насколько я понял drdb полностью копирует в обе стороны данный на диске/в папке.
Не нашел информации в интернете можно ли полностью в drdb засунуть данные и clickhouse и postgre для синхронизации между серверами в пассивной кластеризации.
у меня стоит задача сделать пассивную кластеризацию на двух физических серверах. есть на сервере такие сущности как postgre, clickhouse, redis и сервер на node. все элементы связаны только с нодой.
Пытался найти информацию по этому поводу. узнать можно ли это реализовать, и если можно то как и стоит ли оно того?

За клик - не могу пока сказать, но для пг - посмотри в эту сторону: https://github.com/vitabaks/postgresql_cluster

Если вкратце - то нет, вы таким образом не сможете кластеризовать ни PostgreSQL, ни ClickHouse - только сломать.
Данные СУБД не рассчитывают на то, что доступ к одним и тем же файлам СУБД имеют одновременно два экземпляра сервера СУБД (а де-факто именно это и получится, если вы начнёте синхронизировать через DRBD файловую систему между двумя машинами, на каждой из которых запущено по экземпляру СУБД).
